# django modelformset_factory(User) provides two formsets

Tags: django, django-authentication, user-profile, django-forms

I have tried to use modelformset_factory(User) to create a form to add (and in next step edit) a user.

I'm confused, why it creates a form with my current user and an empty one for a new one?

Any Idea how i could remove the one with the current?

Here is my view.py code:

```
@login_required
def update_or_edit_user_profile(request, UserID = None, template_name='userprofile_form.html'):


    #check when a userid is provided if its the personal or if the user is allowed to edit the profile
    if UserID != None:
        if (request.user.has_perm('change_user_profile') or request.user.pk == UserID):
            pass
        else:
             raise PermissionDenied

    # when user is allowed to continue:
    UserFormSet = modelformset_factory(User)


    if request.method == 'POST':
        userformset = UserFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if userformset.is_valid():
            newUser=userformset.save()
    else:
        userformset = UserFormSet()

    return render_to_response(template_name, {
        "userformset": userformset,
    })
```

and my template:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ userformset.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Send message" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing forms with formsets. A formset is a collection of forms, so Django is giving you exactly what you asked for. If you only want a single form, then that's what you should use:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User


def update_or_edit_user_profile...

    user = User.objects.get(pk=UserID)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = UserForm(instance=User)

    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: yes you are right, I've mixed them up ;). Thanks for your quick response. One open point. Why is the formest filled with my current user?